# What voltage do electrical fly killers use?

Tags: high-voltage

I am interested in the voltage used in electrical fly killers - does anyone **know** (no speculation please) the voltages generally employed? To be clear, I am talking about mains powered, wall-mounted devices.

I would also be interested in the general topologies used - I am guessing some sort of self-resonant flyback with an unrectified output. Anyone know for sure? I haven't pulled one apart yet...

Comment: http://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/107500-indoor-mosquito-bats-explained/

Comment: I have one with a coil directly wired to the plug; 230V (UK mains)

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. - I realise I left some critical details out of my original question. Best I can tell from your link is <630Vpk , but useful all the same. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen 120V ones and I have seen 1.2kV ones. There is no definite answer - It highly depends on the type and manufacturer.

Comment: How many volts kills (or permanently inhibits) a fly is the real question hiding beneath.

Comment: @Andyaka not quite - that's a factor in design, I am more interested in what exists already. Not looking to roll my own, simply to reappropriate what exists. I would wager it's mA (or uA) that kills or inhibits at the biological level, with impulse energy / temperature rise causing explosion taking over for team physics at higher power / smaller fly level.

Comment: _Flyback_ seems appropriate. Will web-apps eventually replace these?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is the fly-kill voltage is the base minimum and actual devices will be this voltage plus a bit (or a lot more).

Comment: @Anday aka Ah but how many volts produce the satisfying sound and light show that will keep customers coming back to buy more zappers?

Comment: I suspect that those wall-mounted ones are extreme overkill for a fly.  I've seen a handheld swatter-shaped one powered by a pair of AA batteries in the handle and even that is fairly effective.  Also, the wall-mounted ones are usually equipped with a UV light source that attracts the flies to it in the first place, so a lot of the power may be going to that and not the fly-murdering parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I visited a factory making the 50/60Hz transformer type some years ago. They were several kV (3-4kV) and similar in construction to ballast transformers for neon signs, but without the magnetic shunts to increase the output impedance.

These ones create quite a profound arc which is intended to burn the insect off the grids. Here's a photo of one from Alibaba:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One which I repaired once used rectified 240V mains with a doubler, so about 680V

Answer (score 2):

Here's a teardown video of a cheap plug-in type, which uses voltage doublers to product -630V and +630V across the grid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtXmsxRdiUw